# how to get all files and folder(with names) from their parent folder on drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want to read all files and folders in a folder on drive. FileList has method called getItems() which return list of files but it has method to get their id but no method to get their names ?

Comment: Have you looked at the example code on this page https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list ? It will return an `ArrayList<File>` object.

Comment: getItems is a list of files, which are described https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Comment: I figured out getTitle returns name of file but problem turned out to inconsistency between drive and what code is returning i.e. I deleted two folders on drive from browser and they still show up when I debug code in eclipse. Why is it happening like this ?

Comment: solved: it was returning folder from trash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getTitle` to return the title (filename) of the file. Remember, the listing returns trashed items. If you want to prevent that, pass the query:

```
q='trashed = false'
```